# Quick way to de-list a nested list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
N_y=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,3],[2,5,8]]]
```

How do I breakdown `N_y` to just one list of items, ie:

Output expected: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,3],[2,5,8]]`

My attempt:

```
j=str(N_y)[1:-1]
print j
```

Output `"[[1,2,3],[4,5,3],[2,5,8]]"`

The problem now is, `j` comes out as a sting. Is there a quick method for de-listing without outputting strings?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: does the outer list always have just one element?

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply fetch the inner list:

```
N_y = N_y[0]
```

If `N_y` initially contains:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 3], [2, 5, 8]]]
```

Afterwards, it will contain:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 3], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: If you want to keep the reference you can do `N_y[:] = N_y[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
>>> N_y[0]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 3], [2, 5, 8]]
>>>
```